# Issue in LSTM Input Dimensions in Keras

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras, lstm, keras-layer

I am trying to implement a multi-input LSTM model using keras. The code is as follows:

```
data_1 -> shape (1150,50) 
data_2 -> shape (1150,50)
y_train -> shape (1150,50)

input_1 = Input(shape=data_1.shape)
LSTM_1 = LSTM(100)(input_1)

input_2 = Input(shape=data_2.shape)
LSTM_2 = LSTM(100)(input_2)

concat = Concatenate(axis=-1)
x = concat([LSTM_1, LSTM_2])
dense_layer = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=[dense_layer])

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                      optimizer='adam',
                      metrics=['acc'])

model.fit([data_1, data_2], y_train, epochs=10)
```

When I run this code, I get a ValueError:

ValueError: Error when checking model input: expected input_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1150, 50)

Do anyone have any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `data1 = np.expand_dims(data1, axis=2)`, before you define the model. `LSTM` expects inputs with dimensions `(batch_size, timesteps, features)`, so, in your case, I guessing you have 1 feature, 50 time steps and 1150 samples, you need to add a dimension at the end of your vector.

This need to be done before you define the model otherwise when you set `input_1 = Input(shape=data_1.shape)` you are telling keras that your input has 1150 timesteps and 50 features,so it will expect inputs of shape `(None, 1150, 50)` (the non stands for "any dimension will be accepted").

The same holds for `input_2`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But this gives another error: `Error when checking model input: expected input_2 to have shape (None, 1150, 50) but got array with shape (1150, 50, 1)`

Comment: As I said in the answer, you need to do `data2 = np.expand_dims(data2, axis=2)` before you initialize the inputs or you'll get that kind of error

Comment: Ok. The problem was with axis. `data_1 = np.expand_dims(data_1, axis=0)` worked for me.